# How to convert a Hashmap into Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary that contains a map field in C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, hashmap

I've been trying to figure out how to convert a `Hashmap` with a map field inside and convert it into a
`Android.Runtime.JavaDictionary` map I can use to store into lists locally and temporarily on a Xamarin app.

I thought there would be a similar structure in Java like: `HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>` that I've seen in some Java code, but C# doesn't recognize it.

I'd very much like to know if it can contain it and how.

Thanks!

Comment: Could it work ?

Comment: No... :(  I had to do a workaround using other data structures like using lists and classes to temporarily hold it and just pass them along with intents. I have come across another problem trying to read the maps from JavaDictionary<string, java.lang.object>.

The JavaDictionary.Values are returned as Icollections<java.lang.object> and can't be read. I'll be posting a new question. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) in C#.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

Comment: It prints out: "Hashmap*****" instead of the values. I have been trying to convert through different ways. I still can't get it. I can get the key because it is string. I can's use the Systems.Collection.Generic.Dictionary from But the JavaDicitonary returns